# Conditional show of an element in the view if an object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

Below is a part of my view template.

```
%ul.property_list
%li.lastminute
  %span.icon
  %h5 #{house.lastminute}
  %h6 #{house.lastminute_conditions}
 %li.guest
  %span.icon
  %h5 #{house.guests}
```

Some houses have a last-minute sale and some do not. If the `lastminute` attribute is filled I want to show the `%li.lastminute` block. If the `lastminute` attribute is empty the `%li.lastminute` is not showed. How and what is the best approach to do this? A condition in the view?

Comment: you will have to put a condition in the view in this case i guess. start the condition with a hyphen ( - ) for haml to understand that its code. the condition itself is really simple ( - if house )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%ul.property_list
%li.lastminute
  %span.icon
  - if house.lastminute
    %h5 #{house.lastminute}
  %h6 #{house.lastminute_conditions}
 %li.guest
  %span.icon
  %h5 #{house.guests}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
%h5 #{house.lastminute} if house.lastminute.present?
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to have a condition in the presentation layer (view). Its not bad either because what you want to change in the presentation logic (how user sees it).

But I would prefer having a helper method to handle your login

1 - Its clean

2 - If your conditional logic gets more complex, it will be easier to manage

My preferred solution would be having a helper method

in your helper module

```
def lastminute?(lastminute)
  lastminute.nil?
end
```

in your view

```
- if lastminute?(house.lastminute)
  %li.lastminute
    %span.icon
    %h5 #{house.lastminute}
    %h6 #{house.lastminute_conditions}
```

HTH :D